# Polynomial interpolating sequence mod p has small degree

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $a_1, a_2,...,a_p$ be integers. Prove that the following two conditions are equivalent:

1) There exists a polynomial $P(x)$ with degree $\leq \frac{p-1}{2}$ such that $P(i) \equiv a_i \pmod p$ for all $1 \leq i \leq p$

2) For any natural $d \leq \frac{p-1}{2}$, 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^p (a_{i+d} - a_i )^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
where indices are taken $\pmod p$

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: By the way, this is CMO 2015 day 1 Question 3.

Comment: My Chinese is not up to the task, but [looks like @Element118 is right](http://www.zyymat.com/chinese-mathematical-olympiad-cmo-2016.html/cmo-2016-day-1). If I got it right the contest was held on December 16th, so it is ok to post and discuss the problems. Wonder why math110 is not posting this (rolls eyes)?

Answer (score 2):

We will express our expressions in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

First notice that the statement does not change if the bound on $d$ is omitted: you may replace $d$ by $-d$, and for $d=0$ the condition is satisfied; so we may allow all $d\in\mathbb{F}_p$.

The main tool in the solution is this identity. If $0\le m<2p-2$ is a nonnegative integer then 
$$
\sum_{i\in\mathbb{F}_p} i^m = \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } m=p-1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise.} \\ \end{cases}
$$
(we define $0^0=1$.)

Proof: The case $m=0$ is trivial.
For $m=p-1$ we can apply Fermat's theorem. In the remaining cases take a 
primitive root $g$ modulo $p$. Then
$$ 
\sum_{\in\mathbb{F}_p} i^m  = \sum_{j=1}^{p-1} g^{jm} \equiv \frac{g^{m(p-1)}-1}{g^m-1}=0.
$$

Now let $P(x)$ be the unique polynomial with $P(i)\equiv a_i\pmod{p}$ and $D=\deg P\le p-1$. We can expand $(P(x+y)-P(x))^2$ as
$$
(P(x+y)-P(x))^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{2p-4} a_k(y) x^k
$$
with some polynomials $a_k(y)$. (Notice that $\deg_x(P(x+y)-P(x))=D-1\le p-2$.)
We focus on the coefficient $a_{p-1}(y)$.

If $D\le\frac{p-1}2$ then $\deg_x (P(x+y)-P(x))^2=2(D-1)<p-1$, so $a_{p-1}(y)=0$. Hence, for every $d$ we have
$$
\sum_{i\in\mathbb{F}_p} (P(i+d)-P(i))^2 = 
\sum_{i\in\mathbb{F}_p} \sum_{k=0}^{p-2} a_k(d) i^k =
\sum_{k=0}^{p-2} a_k(d) \sum_{i\in\mathbb{F}_p}^p i^k =
\sum_{k=0}^{p-2} a_k(d) \cdot 0 .
$$

If $D\ge\frac{p-1}2+1=\frac{p+1}2$, then we claim that the polynomial $a_{p-1}$ is nonzero. Indeed, if the leading term in $P$ is $Ax^D$, then the coefficient of $x^{p-1}y^{2D-p+1}$ in 
$(P(x+y)-P(x))^2$ is $\Big(A\binom{D}{(p-1)/2}\Big)^2\ne0$. 
The degree of $a_{p-1}(y)$ is $2D-p+1<p$.

Hence, there is a value $d$ such that $a_{p-1}(d)\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. For that $d$ we have
$$
\sum_{i\in\mathbb{F}_p}^p (P(i+d)-P(i))^2 = 
\sum_{i\in\mathbb{F}_p}^p \sum_{k=0}^{2p-4} a_k(d) i^k =
\sum_{k=0}^{2p-4} a_k(d) \sum_{\in\mathbb{F}_p}^p i^k =
-a_{p-1}(d) \ne 0.
$$